# $\lim_{x,y \to 0} \frac{\sin(xy)}{x^2 + y^2}$

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

I need help proving that $\displaystyle\lim_{x,y\to 0}\frac{\sin(xy)}{x^2+y^2}$ doesn't exist.

I've tried fixing $x$ and $y$ such as $(x,0)$, $(0,y)$ unsuccessfully, seem to approach the same value which proves nothing.

Also, I am not sure how to correctly use L’Hospital in this case.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 2):

If $y=x$, you get $\dfrac{\sin(x^2)}{2x^2}$, and $\lim_{x\to0}\dfrac{\sin(x^2)}{2x^2}=\dfrac12$.

Answer (score 1):

If $y=x$ we have that the function outside the origin equals $\frac{\sin(x^2)}{2x^2}=\frac{1}{2} \frac{\sin(x^2)}{x^2} \to \frac{1}{2}$ as $x \to 0$.

Answer (score 1):

If you approach to $(0,0)$ along the path $x=y$, the limit is

$$ \lim\limits_{x\to0}\; \frac{\sin(x^2)}{2x^2}= \frac 1 2, $$

while along the path $y=x^2\;$ it is

$$ \lim\limits_{x\to0}\; \frac{\sin(x^3)}{x^2+x^4} = \lim\limits_{x\to0}\;\frac{\sin(x^3)}{x^2(1+x^2)} = \lim\limits_{x\to0}\;\left(\frac{\sin(x^3)}{x^3}\cdot\frac{x}{1+x^2}\right) = 1\cdot 0 = 0.
$$

Therefore the limit doesn't exists, because a necessary condition for the limit to exist is that it is independent of the path taken.